# Why does activator fail with "Could not retrieve Scala 2.11.5: missing scala.Option, scala.tools.nsc.Global" at startup?

Tags: scala, typesafe-activator

I'm using Typesafe Activator **1.3.2** on Windows 8.

Whenever I try to start activator using `activator` command, I am getting the following error:

```
C:\path>activator
Getting Scala 2.11.5 (for activator-launcher)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 6 already retrieved (0kB/15ms)
Error: Could not retrieve Scala 2.11.5: missing scala.Option, scala.tools.nsc.Global
```

Can any one help me on this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure the following directories have been corrupted and should be removed in that order:

- `~/.ivy2`
- `~/.sbt`

You may also want to rename them first before deleting (in case deleting them does not help and could be restored easily rather than *downloading the whole Internet again*).

I'm not on Windows and can't tell you exactly what `~` is resolved to on Windows 8 - it's the home directory of the logged-in user, and unless I'm mistaken it was something like `%userprofile%`.

Answer (score 5):

Deleting

```
 ~/.sbt/boot
```

fixes this issue.

Comment: If this is true, then add extra information to show that it is the solution. Perhaps quotes from sources or the like.

Comment: Scala compiler and standard library, are downloaded to the shared directory $HOME/.sbt/boot/, So may be this directory has been corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and Install

1) Scala plugin in intelliJ

2) SBT  plugin  in intelliJ

Restart the intelliJ   and run the apps  agian.

Answer (score 0):

**The below solution has worked for me.**

**NOTE: Below answer is specific to IntelliJ. But trying the same approach in Eclipse or other IDEs will also work.**

In most cases your project JDK is not compatible with Scala or sbt version, try to change the Scala Compile Server SDK.

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open Settings/Preferences dialog.
2. From the options on the left, select Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Scala | Scala Compiler Server.
3. In the JVM SDK field specify the appropriate SDK.

[image]

I recommend that you switch to Java 8 SDK since the Scala version 2.12, and sbt versions 1.10 and later are not compatible with older Java SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting below two folders fixed the intelliJ error for me

1. rm -rf ~/.ivy2
2. cd ~/.sbt
3. rm -rf boot